# Shortest depth on Clifford+T to decompose a Toffoli

Tags: quantum-algorithms, gate-synthesis

I am looking for a reference providing a circuit that has the smallest possible depth, without ancilla, once the Toffoli has been decomposed on Clifford+T gateset, where Clifford is generate by cNOT, Hadamard and S gate for instance.

So far I found this circuit from [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.0974.pdf) ref.

[image]

However the purpose of their paper is to minimize the T-depth, and not the "global" depth. I guess that the circuit given is however not far from the minimum depth, but I would like to know if there are smaller depth circuit (ideally without extra ancilla).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140206/discussion-on-question-by-marco-fellous-asiani-shortest-depth-on-cliffordt-to-d).

Answer (score 3):

[Amy et al.](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6516700) implemented a meet-in-the-middle algorithm that produces depth-optimal circuits. For the Toffoli, they find the optimal depth to be 8 (Fig 7. a), so one less than the circuit you are showing here (if I count correctly).